# Powershell script with PHP

Tags: php, powershell

I am new to PHP and using WAMP and trying  to do  ...call an powershell script using php but it doesnt show my any output upon submit .

Here is code:

```
   HTML :
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Tool</title>
  <body><center><h1>Welcome</h1><center/>
  <p><img src="images/google.gif"></p>
  <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="number"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

   welcome.php code :

   <html>
   <body>
   <?php
   $CMD = 'powershell -command C:\wamp\www\Badge\scripts\badge.ps1 ' . $_POST['number'];
   ?>
   </body>
  </html>
```

I just get a blank page but it redirects the page to localhost/badge/welcome.php upon submit

My powershell code runs if i give like this

```
  powershell.exe -command C:\wamp\www\Badge\scripts\badge.ps1 12345 and it displays my name.
```

Even i tried having this in php as well :

```
 <?php
 shell_exec ($_POST("powershell.exe -command C:\wamp\www\Badge\scripts\badge.ps1 ['number']");
 shell_exec("exit");
  ?>
```

So any ideas on what might be wrong or what changes i need to make call the text value of html to powershell using php .

Comment: Could you add the powershell code in to your post?

Comment: if(!(Get-PSSnapin |
    Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement"})) {
      ADD-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
    }

Get-QADuser  -ObjectAttributes @{'extensionattribute10'= $args[0]} | select name

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the command flag if you're just passing the script. Also, I find that when I execute the script via PHP it gets blocked by the default ExecutionPolicy setting, you can overwrite it with a flag. Try this:

```
$cmd = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned C:\wamp\www\Badge\scripts\badge.ps1 '.$_POST['number'];
if(exec($cmd, $out)){
    echo join($out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Firts, before you can using powershell on php you must open the powershell on Windows(no using php) and type this script in powershell window (without quotes) "Set-ExcetuionPolicy RemoteSigned". To verify this change type this command on window powershell(without quotes) "Get-ExecutionPolicy" if you show "RemoteSigned" text, your changes is successfully.

2.Second, now you can using php to access powershell. You can't using double quotes in exec comand to powershell. I don't why but when i try that return error. Try this code with single quotes command.

```
$output = array();
$return_code = 0;
$last_line = exec('powershell.exe Write-Host  Hello World!  ', $output, $return_code);

echo "<pre>";
 print_r($output); 
echo "</pre>";
```

And this code with ps script.

```
$output = array();
$return_code = 0;
$last_line = exec('powershell.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\powershell\powerscript2.ps1  2>&1 ', $output, $return_code);

echo "<pre>";
 print_r($output); 
echo "</pre>";
```

And this sample powerscript2.ps1

```
# Filename: Hello.ps1
Write-Host
Write-Host 'Hello World!'
Write-Host "Good-bye World! `n"
# end of script
```